# how to nest a child resource under an edit

Tags: ember.js

I have the following router.

```
App.Router.map(function() {

this.resource('people', function(){

    this.resource('person', { path:'/:person_id' }, function(){
        this.resource('addresses', function(){
            this.resource('addressTypes');
            this.resource('address', { path:'/:address_id' }, function(){
                this.route('edit');
            });
            this.route('create');
        });
        this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
});
```

This allows me to route from people -> person -> address. To edit person I would go people -> person -> edit (person). To edit address I would go: people -> person -> address -> edit(address).But what I want to do is people -> person -> edit -> addressEdit. That is, I want to nest the addressEdit under the (person) edit route so that if i transition to personEdit, which links to the child addresses, I will then be able to click on an address and go straight to addressEdit. In other words, although person and address are two different models, I want the edit of person to include the edit of address.

During edit (of person ID 1), moving to address (address ID 11 belonging to person ID 1), I would expect the url to look like : app/#/people/1/edit/addresses/11/edit

Here is my failed attempt to express this in code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

this.resource('people', function(){

    this.resource('person', { path:'/:person_id' }, function(){
        this.resource('addresses', function(){
            this.resource('addressTypes');
            this.resource('address', { path:'/:address_id' }, function(){
                //this.route('edit');
            });
            this.route('create');
        });
        //this.route('edit');
        this.resource('edit', function(){
            this.resource('addresses', function(){
                this.resource('addressTypes');
                this.resource('addressEdit', { path:'/:address_id' }, function(){
                    //this.route('edit');
                });
                this.route('create');
            });
        });
    });
    this.route('create');
});
```

});

Changing the route('edit') into a resource('edit'..) immediately breaks the app when transitioning from /app/people/1 to /edit: "The route person.edit was not found".

Could you offer any guidence? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resource.route`  the link-to should now be `edit`.  I'd probably rename it to `personEdit`

```
this.resource('personEdit', {path:'edit'}, function(){
```

Comment: Thank you. A succinct and correct answer! To transition from `person` to person edit I am using an action in the `personController`; once I used your code, I updated the action from `this.transitionToRoute('person.edit')` to `this.transitionToRoute('personEdit')`. For the sake of those that might not know, specifying a resource resets the naming hierarchy to the name specified in the resource.

Comment: thanks for filling in the blanks, i just had shoulder surgery and one handed pecking is slow :)